# Typescript dynamic access property variable

Tags: typescript

i have a list of variables

```
lstrData1:string 
lstrData2:string 
lstrData3:string 
lstrData4:string 
lstrData5:string
```

is there any way to assign values to variable in loop ?

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
   this["lstrData" + i ]) =i
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use js es6 destructuring like:

create an object that property name like variables and assign values to the properties, is more clean than you loop in array.

example:

```
const obj = { var1: ‘value’ };
{var1} = obj ;
var1 // value
```